# Have very big trouble with my choice generator

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried to make an button that random picks an answer if you click on it; there are no  errors shown, I don't know if I made any mistakes.

**activity main java**

```
package infuso.choicemaster;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import infuso.choicemaster.R;
public class activity_main extends AppCompatActivity  {
    public Button Generate;
    public TextView einleitung;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] myNames = {"Call the 3rd  person in your Phonebook and ask for activities", "Drive 5 miles with your car just for fun", "Call the 14th person in your Phonebook and ask for activities ",
                "Send a message at whatsapp to a random people in your contacts", "Do a workout",
                "Play old games like n64,playstation 1 or whatever", "Make funny selfies", "Cook something you want", "Watch some films", "Make fresh orange juice ",
                "Climb on a tree", "See how long you can hold a note", "Try to not think about penguins", "Pretend to be a car", "Make Star Trek door noises", "Watch TV, repeat everything said in Italian accent",
                "Buy a postcard an send it to your friend", "Buy a unicorn", "Put a walkie talkie in your mail box and shout at everybody who walks by", "Sing the Llama song till you've annoyed everyone in the room",
                "Start talking in a made up language", "Call your friend, and tell them you can't talk right now, cause your busy", "Go into an elevator with a piece of chalk, draw a box and declare the area your personal space"
                , "Put vanilla pudding in a jar that says MAYO and then eat it in a public place", "go to kfc dressed like a gangster and ask if they have black fried chicken until they kick you out"
                , "Dance around your house"};
        Generate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method sub
                int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 26);
                einleitung.setText(myNames[rando]);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        Generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        einleitung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        final TextView textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        Button Generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Generate.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

**activity main xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:text="@string/einleitung"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="32dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="288dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="97sp" />
```

**strings xml**

```
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Choice Master</string>
<string name="button">Generate</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="einleitung">Welcome to Choice Master 1.0</string>
</resources>
```

**Android Manifest xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="infuso.choicemaster" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.infuso.ChoiceMaster.activity_main" >
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know what you need, so I included it all.

Comment: Where do you need help exactly?

Comment: I see some problems in your source code. You "find" button and textview in onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu). This should be called in onCreate() method. Also, Generate.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this); will not work.

Comment: i think i have problems with androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using findViewById inside the onCreateOptionsMenu to initialize the local variable. It will not assign the object for your instance variables so you will get a NullPointerException in the following line:

```
Generate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Modify your code as given below, it will work.

```
package infuso.choicemaster;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class activity_main extends AppCompatActivity  {
    public Button Generate;
    public TextView einleitung;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Initialize the instance variables
        Generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        einleitung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

        final String[] myNames = {"Call the 3rd  person in your Phonebook and ask for activities", "Drive 5 miles with your car just for fun", "Call the 14th person in your Phonebook and ask for activities ",
                "Send a message at whatsapp to a random people in your contacts", "Do a workout",
                "Play old games like n64,playstation 1 or whatever", "Make funny selfies", "Cook something you want", "Watch some films", "Make fresh orange juice ",
                "Climb on a tree", "See how long you can hold a note", "Try to not think about penguins", "Pretend to be a car", "Make Star Trek door noises", "Watch TV, repeat everything said in Italian accent",
                "Buy a postcard an send it to your friend", "Buy a unicorn", "Put a walkie talkie in your mail box and shout at everybody who walks by", "Sing the Llama song till you've annoyed everyone in the room",
                "Start talking in a made up language", "Call your friend, and tell them you can't talk right now, cause your busy", "Go into an elevator with a piece of chalk, draw a box and declare the area your personal space"
                , "Put vanilla pudding in a jar that says MAYO and then eat it in a public place", "go to kfc dressed like a gangster and ask if they have black fried chicken until they kick you out"
                , "Dance around your house"};
        Generate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method sub
                int rando = (int) (Math.random() * 26);
                einleitung.setText(myNames[rando]);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
I have not notice this:
In your Manifest file, the activity name is provided incorrectly. Check the class name.

```
<activity
            android:name="infuso.choicemaster.activity_main" >
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Additional to that, delete the "import infuso.choicemaster.R;" from the Java code.

**Edit 2:**
Working sample of the project:
[Choice Master](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxotp3vas282ir5/ChoiceMaster.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Error:infuso.choicemaster.activity_main is not an activity subclass or alias    to hard :D thank you 1000 times for your help !!! ^^ it is 8 oclock in the morning the app has stolen my time so fast :D im going to bed now maybe you finde the mistakes that i made when i am energyzed in a few hours i will keep work on ! :)

Comment: I have added a working sample at the following link. Download it and open it in AndroidStudio :)
[Choice Master Project Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxotp3vas282ir5/ChoiceMaster.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Thank You Gobinath!!!!! You are the best !!! :) i check both and look for my mistakes ! thanks man you made my day :):):):)

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned anything to `Generate` or to `einleitung`. Both of these are null and you will get a `NullPointerException` when you call any method on them.

After you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, you need to have

```
generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
einleitung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. textview1);
```

**EDIT**: And get rid of that stuff in OnCreateOptionsMenu. It should only be used for menu stuff, not obtaining references to views.

(aside: you should also change the name of the button to `generate` in your activity since capitalized words usually indicate a class name.)

Comment: now it says i doesnt have manifest activity main and its not a subclass or alias